# Appendix Figures cited 'Appendix .II'

Tags: appendices, ref

I am trying to cite my Appendix figures using the \ref command, but for some reason it displays the citations as " Appendix .I", I would like to remove the full stop before the number. 
Any idea how to do that? 
Here is my minimal work example:

```
  \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
  \author{Maria}
  \begin{document}


\ref{alignment}



\appendix
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Appendix}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\Roman{figure}}  
\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\Roman{table}} 
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dupcntr}[2]{%
\expandafter\let\csname c@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname c@#2\endcsname
}
\makeatother
\dupcntr{table}{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Alignment species primers, including NCBI accession number.}
\label{alignment}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\textbf{Species}                                    & \textbf{Gene} &                
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the "." ("full stop") prefix before appendix figures and tables, just change

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\Roman{figure}}  
\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\Roman{table}}
```

to

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{\Roman{figure}}  
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}
```